# Laravel Ajax controller with single route

Tags: ajax, laravel

Just wondering if this is a good way to write ajax code to interact with Laravel routes?

Example my application's require to list all customer data and also list all country through ajax. I have 3 controller ApiController, CustomerController, CountryController.

So in my routes.php I have this routes

```
Route::get('api/v1/ajax/json/{class}/{function}', 'Api\v1\ApiController@ajaxreturnjson');
```

In the ApiController.php, I have below function to call other controller function to return the data I need.

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function ajaxreturnjson(Request $request, $controller, $function){
        $input = $request->input();
        if($request->input('namespace') != ''){
            $namespace = $request->input('namespace');
            unset($input['namespace']);
        }else{
            $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
        }
        $data = array();
        try {
          $app = app();
          $controller = $app->make($namespace.'\\'.$controller);
          $data = $controller->callAction($function, array($request)+$input);

        } catch(\ReflectionException $e){
          $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

So example to use the ajax, I just need to pass the class name, namespace and also the function name to the ajax url.

Example to retrieve all customer info.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:"json",
  url:"api/v1/ajax/json/CustomerController/getList",
  data:"namespace=\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\",
  success:function(data){

  }
})
```

So in this way, I don't have to create so many routes for different ajax request.

But I am not sure if this will cause any security issue or is this a bad design?

Comment: Put your question on `codereview`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not do it this way. Sure, you *could* do it this way, but it's not very semantic and debugging it could be a pain.

Also, if someone else begins working on the project, when they look at your routes file, they won't have any idea how your app is structured or where to go to find things.

I think it's better to have a controller for each Thing.

Comment: Who thumbed down this answer? Readability is a legitimate concern. Will upvote this one.